# Remove tabs from file

Tags: unix, sed, tr

We are receiving a file that is delimited into columns with tabs (\t). When there is a tab present in one of the "fields" of the file, it comes in as a special tab with two backslashes (\tab).

This is causing a problem with our ETL software, so I am wondering how to take these double backslash files out prior to processing, but the sed syntax I'm using is not working:

```sh
sed "s/$(printf \\\t)/ /g"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you also provide a sample input that is failing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the shell from interpreting the backslashes by adding sinfgle quotes and add enough backslashes for sed to work on:

```
sed "s/$(printf '\\\\\t')/ /g"
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

As a followup however, we have \\n characters that also need to be removed. The logical:

sed "s/$(printf '\\\\\n')/ /g" 

does not remove the \n, only the backslash before it? Any idea why?